# Encoding - issue displaying dutch characters

Tags: c#, encoding

I want to dynamically create an email and send it. So far so good, the problem is that it's in dutch language and it doesn't display correctly.

I am doing this:

```
// Body Html
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailMessage.BodyHtml))
{
    var encoding = Encoding.UTF32;

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(emailMessage.BodyHtml);
    byte[] unicodeArray = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), encoding, byteArray);
    emailMessage.BodyHtml = encoding.GetString(unicodeArray);



    System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
    ct.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Html;
    AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(emailMessage.BodyHtml, ct);
    mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
    htmlView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
}

try
{

    smtpSender.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

The mail should contain `Financiële details` but when i open the mail with outlook i see `Financiele details`

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you certain the original contains an `ë` and not an `e`?

Comment: Why do you use a codepage? I'm not sure that's recorded in Mime and the reader also has to use that page. Have you tried UTF-8 ?

Comment: Did you try to use the Encoding setting in the AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the InternetCodepage property of the Outlook mailitem. I had a similar issue with a new e-Mail in which I inserted text from an existiing e-mail, in which German Umlauts didn't displaying correctly. This was solved after I set the InternetCodepage in the new e-mail to the appropriate value of the original e-mail.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860730.aspx for more information about this property and a list of possible values.